# Embedded GNU C Library: Binaries

Tags: update-manager

Update manager is showing "Embedded GNU C Library: Binaries" under important security updates.

Why is that? (I am on a laptop do i really need them?)

Update: 
Just to make it clear, I know what **C** is, and I usually program in it.
Hence, I am familiar with `glibc` not `eglibc`.

So, what is `eglibc` required for? or what is the difference between glibc & eglibc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite its name eglibc is not only used for embedded systems and as a matter of fact Ubuntu uses eglibc as its primary and only libc since version 9.10.

So unless you installed glibc yourself, eglibc is the only C library you have.

As such almost all applications on your system depend on it and it is an integral part of your system.

So you should definitely update it.

Answer (score 3):

Many programs on Ubuntu require C libraries to run.

C is a programming language that quite a lot of applications are written in.

A library is not an application in itself but a collection of classes (instructions) that other programs can make use of. They are an integral part of the Ubuntu operating system and nothing to worry about, although they are necessary regardless of the system you are on.

Comment: question updated. Apologies for throwing incomplete information at you :).

Answer (score 3):

From the package manager:

> Contains the standard libraries that
>   are used by nearly all programs on the
>   system. This package includes shared
>   versions of the standard C library and
>   the standard math library, as well as
>   many others.

Libc is important to the core of the system, and a security update to it must be of very high priority. I would run any upgrade marked "security".

Comment: question updated. Apologies for throwing incomplete information at you :).

Comment: I actually knew this. I read Debian switched to eglibc. It is just a compatible variant of the regular one.

Answer (score 2):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc
Here is an overview of the library, Chances are that it is already installed and needs updating to fix a security flaw. Some of the programs on the system probably need it to run. Unless your massively concerned about space I would install it...

Comment: The "Embedded" in the package description is quite misleading especially as this **is** the source of the non-embedded, regular, basic essential libc6.

Comment: @msw : may be misleading, but there has to be some difference between `glibc` & `eglibc`. And, if nothing uses eglibc on my laptop, then I shall not update it.

Comment: @N1.1: eglibc is the only libc you have. Ubuntu doesn't ship with the "normal" glibc anymore. So everything uses eglibc on your system.

Comment: How do you know nothing is using eglibc though? You might as well either remove it or update it. Surely updating is the best thing to do if it is being used and removing is the best thing if its not used by any applications. I don't understand whats the problem with updating it? Is it a big update?

Comment: @rocker: I didn't know :), that being the reason i asked here.

Comment: The "Embedded" is because *e*glibc is a fork of glibc that is made more modular, which makes it possible to build smaller, "incomplete" versions of it (with non-needed parts removed), and that also makes it better for embedded use of course.

Comment: @N 1.1 I had misread your question then. Or not understood it fully ;)